# Adding up Transformer Output

Tags: voltage, transformer

This Question is regarding to Transformer Power Electronics. I attached two transformers - one is Step Up (220V ; 0.5A) and another is Step Down (6V; 20A) to a same power source (25V ; 5A) in such away that both transformer gets input current alternately. In simple words only one transformer is active at a time and another is off.

So My question is here I am getting two outputs from two transformer alternately. Now I want to add up both output so that the final output must be the constant i.e (250V; 20A). Can anybody tell me that how to add both voltage?

I have some idea in my mind i.e converting both voltage to DC and then add or using RLC circuit in both transformer to get constant output and then add it.

Answer (score 1):

I have some observations and a question.

1) input power is 25 Vac, 5A.  That works out to 125 VA.

2) Transformer #1 is 220 Vac, 0.5A.  That works out to 110 VA.

3) Transformer #2 is 6 Vac, 20A.  That works out to 120 VA.

4) Your desired output is 250V 20A.  That works out to 5000 VA or 5 kVA.

As you can see, the numbers between input and desired output don't match up.  What you are asking for is not possible.

Now for my question:

1) Exactly *HOW* are you arranging things so that only one transformer gets input current alternatively?

Answer (score 1):

As Dwayne Reid said above, this is impossible. From his answer, you can't expect to get more power out than you have available.

As for the transformers themselves, other than the fact that it doesn't make sense that only one transformer gets power at a time, you can't combine a step up and step down transformer to any useful effect.

Consider this, power must be conserved, thus if you start with 25V and 5A, you can step down to 2.5V and 50A (with an ideal transformer), or up to 250V and .5A. In all these cases, you have both an input and output of 125W. Additionally, combining the effects of the transformers would give you your input back! You would step the voltage up, then lower it to its initial state.

If you want to get 250V, you can do so with a 1:10 transformer. It would step up your voltage to the required 250V. If you want 20A, you can do so with a 4:1 transformer, which would step down your voltage to 6.25V, but with 20A sourcing capabilities.

If you want both 250V and 20A, you should consider how extraordinarily dangerous that is, and get a power supply rated to produce that. You can't combine two transformers to do this.